# Polymer 1.0 itemForElement in nested dom-repeat

Tags: polymer-1.0

For example, I have a dom-repeat like this:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" id="rows" items="[[rows]]" as="row">
  <tr class="result-tb-row" closed$=[[row.closed]]>
    <td class="result-tb-data">
      <ul class="violation-list">
        <template id="rowItem" is="dom-repeat" items="[[row.items]]">
          <li on-click="click">[[item]]</li>
        </template>
      <ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

If I want to know which row I am clicking on, I can write a something like this:

```
this.$.rows.itemForElement(event.target);
```

However, what if I want to get the exact item corresponding to `li` I clicked on. How do I do so? I obviously cannot do `this.$.rowItem.itemForElement(event.target)` because `rowItem` isn't unique.

**Update**

`event.model.item` seems to solve this particular problem. But if you have double nested dom-repeat or more and you want to get the middle layers, you're out of luck. Probably have to implement an iterator yourselves. double nested dom-repeat happens a lot in table. Table is already a nested dom-repeat; if you want a dom-repeat inside a table cell (and you will run into it), double nested dom-repeat happens.

It isn't hard to implement an iterator, just hope that the Polymer team supports more methods for nested dom-repeat because this is an awesome feature.

Comment: Did you try `event.model`?

Comment: Use the returned `sender` parameter from the click fn to access the `li`

Answer (score 4):

`event.target` holds a `<li>` reference.

When you do `this.$.rowItem.itemForElement(event.target)`, the `dom-repeat` named `rowItem`  is unique, and it will look what item belongs to that `<li>`.

But if you just want item data, you can use `event.model.item`, which holds a reference to the item data that belongs to the line you clicked.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfectly valid question, I'm facing the same situation. Anyone has a solution?

**UPDATE**

I found the ID in `e.model.__data__`. But this feels like a hack

Answer (score 1):

Here it is. It took me a couple of apps to figure this out.

Polymer considers the inner ID to be a dynamically created ID. So using Polymer's automatic node finding for **dynamic IDs**, you can say:

```
this.$$('#rowItem').itemForElement(event.target)
```

As documented here: 
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding